# ImportError: cannot import name '_rfc_1738_quote'

Tags: sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, spyder

I am trying to connect Jupyter Notebook to Snowflake but getting the below issue

`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-3b4f5d455df9> in <module>
      1 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
----> 2 from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
      3 import sqlalchemy as db
      4 import pandas as pd
      5 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\snowflake\sqlalchemy\__init__.py in <module>
     56     VARIANT,
     57 )
---> 58 from .util import _url as URL
     59 from .version import VERSION
     60 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\snowflake\sqlalchemy\util.py in <module>
     11 from urllib.parse import quote_plus
     12 
---> 13 from sqlalchemy.engine.url import _rfc_1738_quote
     14 
     15 

ImportError: cannot import name '_rfc_1738_quote'
```

`

And here: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/issues/350 it was supposed to upgrade to v1.4.3 version but getting the below error when trying to upgrade.

Used command: pip install snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.4.3

Error

`

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.4.3 (from versions: 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.9, 1.1.10, 1.1.11, 1.1.12, 1.1.13, 1.1.14, 1.1.15, 1.1.16, 1.1.17, 1.1.18, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.4.3
```

`

Can someone please help with the issue?

Tried to upgrade to the latest version which is not the latest.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was resolved by upgrading python to 3.9 and then upgrading sqlalchemy to 1.4.3